# Is it possible to say "proofreading can avoid mistakes"?

Tags: word-choice

Is it possible to say "proofreading can avoid mistakes"?
This is a quote from an online article. I would say "proofreading can prevent mistakes", but I want to understand the word usage.

Comment: I agree with you. The better version is,  "proofreading can prevent mistakes".  Where did you find the text?

Comment: I agree that using "avoid" in this case is weird, and would opt for "prevent". But you could also say something like, *proofreading can help you avoid mistakes".*

Comment: Is that the whole sentence? I think a sentence like "Competent proofreading can avoid mistakes" could work, but it would be referring to mistakes in the proofreading itself. Usually, in the context of proofreading, the mistakes one's thinking of are mistakes in the thing that's being proofread. In that context "prevent" sounds very much better.

Comment: Is there any possibility that it's a joke?

Comment: Proofreading can ensure **you** avoid mistakes. / Proofreading can eliminate mistakes.

Comment: Proofreading *corrects* mistakes after they happen; it does not prevent them from happening in the first place. It does prevent their being published, though. (I refer, of course, to the *marking* rather than the *reading* part of the proofreader's job.)

Comment: @BrianDonovan It depends on whether you consider "mistakes" to refer to the errors in the text or the act of publishing a text that has those errors. Or whether you're considering it from the writer's or reader's perspective (e.g. I hate it when I see grammar mistakes in the newspaper -- proofreading could have avoided them).

Comment: It definitely is possible to say that -- I just did.

Comment: (Actually, "avoid" is more accurate than "prevent'.  If a mistake is present, proofreading can "avoid" it the same way one might avoid a piece of trash in the road by steering around it.  But no magic will make the piece of trash magically vanish such that it can be said to have been "prevented".)

Comment: Here is the original article: https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/10-ways-to-proofread-articles-faster-2795 - I was also wondering about the use of the word "derive" in the third paragraph. Can this be used either way?

Comment: Really, neither "avoid" nor "prevent" is something proofreading can accomplish.  It can only "reduce" or "minimize".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The act of proofreading is meant to identify and fix mistakes. By proofreading you're already supposing that mistakes have been made. There is no avoiding or preventing something that already occurred (unless you have a blue police box). The only way "proofreading can avoid mistakes" would be if Proofreading was an entity, and the fragment was followed with "by taking greater care in their work" or the equivalent. In my opinion I think a better way of putting it would be "proofreading can rectify mistakes".

Comment: From one point of view, this brief analysis is certainly correct. But I am reminded of a saying that one of my first employers was fond of repeating: "It's not a mistake until it leaves this building." So while it would have been an error if it had reached print, a typo caught in manuscript, galleys, or even mechanicals (in the old days) was simply a typo that someone extirpated before it achieved the status of a full-blown mistake—no harm, no foul. In accordance with such a view, good proofreading avoided mistakes or prevented them from seeing the light of day.

Comment: You're absolutely right in context. However, read in a vacuum I felt obligated to be a bit persnickety since the OP wanted help clarify word usage.

Answer (score -2):

I agree that the phrase "proofreading can avoid mistakes" does not sound right.

But I still think if you want to use the word "avoid", you could say "proofreading helps avoid mistakes"

Comment: Why? Please add references and citations to *prove* you are correct, rather than us having to take your word for it.